# Insertar un archivo mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Me ocupa lo siguiente:

Tengo una `function JS` que luego de definir variables y ejecutar varios cálculos al final de ella resuelve:

```
document['getElementById']('foot')['innerHTML'] = foot;
document['getElementById']('botonera')['innerHTML'] = botonera;
```

Yo quisiera saber si es posible hacer un `insert` de un archivo `html` dentro de una `function` de `js` que quede algo así:

```
function a(){
foot= "";
botonera="";

document['getElementById']('foot')['innerHTML'] = foot;
document['getElementById']('botonera')['innerHTML'] = botonera;

document['getElementById']('contenido')['innerHTML'] = include("/include/cuerpo.html");

}
```

Lo que quisiera hacer es que desde esta `function` se envie directamente al `div id=contenido` el contenido de mi archivo `("/include/cuerpo.html")`

Quisiera saber si existe alguna opción que me permita resolver dentro del mismo `javascript` sin recurrir a `jquery`.

Mi proyecto se trata de una web offline, puedo cargar librerías desde CDN pero prefiero incluir las librerías en mi proyecto ya que normalmente las personas que abren este tipo de aplicativos no necesariamente tienen internet por tal motivo el proyecto es cargas offline desde navegadores web con archivos `html`..!

Comment: jQuery está escritor en Javascript, así que SIEMPRE podrás elegir no usarlo

Comment: con jquery dentro del index he utilizado jquery asi $(document).ready(function(){
$('#tablaDatatable').load('../tablagestion.php');
etc etc
Pero ahora este proyecto es offline y quisiera poder implementar algo similar pero dentro de la function JS pero no he logrado el objetivo.

Comment: ¿Estás abriendo el HTML directamente en el navegador, sin tener un servidor WEB instalado?

Comment: Si es un proyecto de una web offline, vulgarmente lo que necesito es que al final de de mi funcion se ejecute un insert de ° 
`("/include/cuerpo.html")`  yo he utilizado la opcion de jquery `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#tablaDatatable').load('../tablagestion.php');` pero en esta oportunidad necesito que dentro de la function JS sea llamado el archivo html en cuestion y se cargue como lo hace con `document['getElementById']('foot')['innerHTML'] = foot;
document['getElementById']('botonera')['innerHTML'] = botonera;` pero en `document['getElementById']('contenido')['innerHTML']`

Comment: Si tu idea es una "web offline", te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a electron. En cualquier caso un navegador sólo permitirá acceder a archivos mediante HTTP(S)

Comment: si es _offline_ lo ideal es que lo publiques en un servidor web local nginx o apache2 y el ejemplo de @PabloLozano funcionaria sin problemas, de hecho lo necesitas ya que en tu codigo se ve que estas usando PHP del lado del backend

Comment: Gracias el ejemplo que coloque es php porque lo copie desde otro proyecto que si esta en uno de nuestros servidores, pero el caso que describo voy a tener que solucionar es copiando todo el codigo de la web cuerpo.html y copiarlo dentro de una variable dentro de mi function..! no queria hacerlo asi ya que de esa forma tengo que colocar todo dentro de una misma linea y modificar el codigo asi es mas complejo en un futuro.

Comment: lo que quieres hacer esta especificado con las respuestas ; pero tu tienes otro problema voto por cerrar esta pregunta necesita ser aclarada!, su problema es de configuracion de un servidor http para una red local

Comment: Gracias, pero el producto que nos ocupa no pretende que cada usuario configure un server local, la idea es que abran el archivo index desde cualquier plataforma que tengan disponibles. De todas maneras gracias..!

Comment: creo que tal vez en el [chat] podramos tratar de aclarar tu pregunta?

Comment: @gbianchi nunca he utilizado esa plataforma de CHAT pero no estoy cerrado a explorar nuevas opciones que me permitan buscar las respuestas que necesito..!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [el API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch):

```
fetch('/mi/documento.html')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = text);
```

Comment: Con la respuesta sugerida me da como resultado el error URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Comment: Con un archivo local es imposible, estoy asumiendo que cargas el HTML desde un servidor web vía HTTP

Comment: Si claro comprendo se me paso colocarlo en el enunciado ya voy a modificarlo..!!